# Collapse GroupBox border without collapsing content

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to collapse the border of a `GroupBox` control in XAML (i.e. bind to a property in the VM) without also collapsing the content?

I don't just want to remove the border, which can be achieved by setting `BorderThickness` to 0 and `Header` to an empty string.  I also want the `GroupBox` content to stretch out over where the border was.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type config:ElementGroup}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HideBorder}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=ItemLabel}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
        </Style>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <GroupBox>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ElementList}" Visibility="Visible">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Path=Columns}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </GroupBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapsing a `GroupBox`, i.e. setting its `Visibility` property to `Hidden` or `Collapse`, will also collapse its `Content`.

If you don't want this, you could define another `ItemsControl` that you display when the `GroupBox` gets collapsed:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type config:ElementGroup}">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=ItemLabel}" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
        </Style>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox x:Name="gb">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ElementList}" Visibility="Visible">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Path=Columns}" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </GroupBox>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ic" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ElementList}" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Path=Columns}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HideBorder}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="gb" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="ic" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Any thoughts about this approach compared to [codeDom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5306861/codedom)'s approach with respect to performance?  The `ElementList` that the `ItemsControl` binds to might contain elements that updates several times per second.

Comment: You are still binding to very same collection with the very same objects, aren't you? Binding to the same source collection twice doesn't create a copy of the collection itself nor the objects in it.

Comment: How about the duplicated ItemsControl?  Will firing off notifications in the VM cause the collapsed ItemsControl also to update and redraw even though it's collapsed, thus consuming additional resources?

Comment: The elements in the ItemTemplate of the collapsed ItemsControl won't be loaded so there is nothing to be re-drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `GroupBox` Style to this:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HideBorder}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"  
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=ItemLabel}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example?  I tried your suggestion, but can't get it to work.  The `GroupBox` only contains a single `ItemsControl`.  But even though I explicitly set the `ItemsControl` `Visibility` property to `Visible`, the whole `GroupBox` and the `ItemsControl` within is gone when setting `GroupBox` `Visibility` to either `Hidden` or `Collapsed`.

Comment: It works great.  But why the Grid values?  Which Grid?  It works just as well without them.

Comment: @Oystein I fixed.